# Hover Color doesn't change CSS3

Tags: css

Assume I have many `<a></a>` tag in my webpage, each of them are with different color. Is that a way that I can do a simple hover css code like below, when hover its color doesnt change, or I have to set it one by one?

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover {
  color: initial;
}
```

Comment: You want your anchors to be different colors, but when you hover them, you want them NOT to change their color?  Stay the same as before you hovered?

Comment: @Godisgood Now that you've mentioned it I'm not sure I fixed the OP's English properly when editing. Rolled back to the original question text.

Comment: Correct @God is good

Comment: So if an anchor is made blue, you want it to stay blue when it is hovered?  If that is the case, then check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need a `:hover` selector for this.  You can keep the links their original color by just setting the specific `<a>` tag rules.  Like this:

```css
.blue {
  color: blue;
  }

.green {
  color: green;
  }

.red {
  color: red;
  }

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
  }

.purple {
  color: purple;
  }
```

```html
<a class="blue" href="alink.html">Click here</a><br/>
<a class="green" href="alink.html">Click here</a><br/>
<a class="red" href="alink.html">Click here</a><br/>
<a class="yellow" href="alink.html">Click here</a><br/>
<a class="purple" href="alink.html">Click here</a><br/>
```

If you want the colors to return to the original color (black).  Then you did it right, but just put `!important` after `color: initial`.

```css
.blue {
  color: blue;
  }

.green {
  color: green;
  }

.red {
  color: red;
  }

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
  }

.purple {
  color: purple;
  }

a:hover {
  
  color: initial !important;
  
  }
```

```html
<a class="blue" href="alink.html">Click here</a><br/>
<a class="green" href="alink.html">Click here</a><br/>
<a class="red" href="alink.html">Click here</a><br/>
<a class="yellow" href="alink.html">Click here</a><br/>
<a class="purple" href="alink.html">Click here</a><br/>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: for the sake of example, i recommend using classes instead of ids, since visitors to this question who see this might be likely to apply the same "color" to multiple tags.